# How do I use a (generic) vector in go?

Tags: vector, go

I am using a Vector type to store arrays of bytes (variable sizes)

```
store := vector.New(200);
...
rbuf := make([]byte, size);
...
store.Push(rbuf);
```

That all works well, but when I try to retrieve the values, the compiler tells me I need to use type assertions.  So I add those in, and try

```
for i := 0; i < store.Len(); i++ {
   el := store.At(i).([]byte); 
...
```

But when I run this it bails out with:

```
interface is nil, not []uint8
throw: interface conversion
```

Any idea how I can 'cast'/convert from the empty Element interface that Vector uses to store its data to the actual []byte array that I then want to use subsequently?

---

**Update (Go1):** The vector package has been removed on [2011-10-18](http://weekly.golang.org/doc/devel/weekly.html#2011-10-18).

Comment: I wonder if all of your rbufs are actually byte arrays when you push them? Can you query the type with a "print reflect.Typeof(store.At(i)).String()" before casting it?

Perhaps a look at the implementation of intvector helps: http://golang.org/src/pkg/container/vector/intvector.go
(and to me, it looks like your use is correct).

Comment: In the end I actually switched to intVectors; I was reading in a UTF-8 string terminated by a line-break, and the rbufs where storing the bytes for later conversion to a string.  But then I found out that I can also turn an array of ints directly into a string, so I am now just pushing ints on that vector, and use 'string(store.Data())' to turn that into a string.

Comment: yes,container/vector is finally dead!There's no container/vector any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works fine for me. Have you initialised the first 200 elements of your vector? If you didn't they will probably be nil, which would be the source of your error.

```
package main

import vector "container/vector"
import "fmt"

func main() {
     vec := vector.New(0);
     buf := make([]byte,10);
     vec.Push(buf);

     for i := 0; i < vec.Len(); i++ {
     el := vec.At(i).([]byte);
     fmt.Print(el,"\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks!  That did it.  I assumed the argument was a Java-style capacity 'hint', rather than a fixed pre-set... But I generally find the go documentation rather terse. And the error messages are not very helpful most of the time either!

Comment: No worries. Remember you can always check the source of go modules in $GOROOT/src/pkg if you're unsure of what's happening

Comment: Note that container/vector has been removed and replaced with slice array wrappers