# undefined vector.New

Tags: vector, go, undefined

From this question

[How do I use a (generic) vector in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726336/how-do-i-use-a-generic-vector-in-go)

I tried to create a new vector but the compiler says it is undefined:

```
$ 6g -V
6g version release.r60.3 9516
$ cat > vectest.go <<.
> package main
> 
> import vector "container/vector"
> import "fmt"
> 
> func main() {
>      vec := vector.New(0);
>      buf := make([]byte,10);
>      vec.Push(buf);
> 
>      for i := 0; i < vec.Len(); i++ {
>      el := vec.At(i).([]byte);
>      fmt.Print(el,"\n");
>      }
> }
> .
$ 6g vectest.go 
vectest.go:7: undefined: vector.New
```

What might be wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [weekly.2011-10-18](http://weekly.golang.org/doc/devel/weekly.html#2011-10-18)
>
> The container/vector package has been deleted. Slices are better.
>   [SliceTricks: How to do vector-esque things with slices.](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks)

I revised [your `convertToLCD` code](https://gist.github.com/2129414) to have better performance: 5,745 ns/op versus 19,003 ns/op.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

const (
    lcdNumerals = `
 _     _  _     _  _  _  _  _ 
| |  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|
|_|  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _|
`
    lcdWidth   = 3
    lcdHeight  = 3
    lcdLineLen = (len(lcdNumerals) - 1) / lcdWidth
)

func convertToLCD(n int) string {
    digits := strconv.Itoa(n)
    displayLineLen := len(digits)*lcdWidth + 1
    display := make([]byte, displayLineLen*lcdHeight)
    for i, digit := range digits {
        iPos := i * lcdWidth
        digitPos := int(digit-'0') * lcdWidth
        for line := 0; line < lcdHeight; line++ {
            numeralPos := 1 + lcdLineLen*line + digitPos
            numeralLine := lcdNumerals[numeralPos : numeralPos+lcdWidth]
            displayPos := displayLineLen*line + iPos
            displayLine := display[displayPos : displayPos+lcdWidth]
            copy(displayLine, string(numeralLine))
            if i == len(digits)-1 {
                display[displayLineLen*(line+1)-1] = '\n'
            }
        }
    }
    return string(display)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", convertToLCD(1234567890))
}
```

Output:

```
    _  _     _  _  _  _  _  _ 
  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|| |
  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _||_|
```

Comment: That's what I end up using, appending slices, not the most performant way though ( suggestions are welcome ) https://gist.github.com/2129414

Comment: @OscarRyz: I've added a faster version of your `convertToLCD` function to my answer.

Comment: @newacct I meant in *my* implementation, because I just appeded strings, not that this was terrible or anything, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 2):

It's true there is no vector.New in r60.3, but rather than patch up this code, you should learn the new append function.  It made the vector package unnecessary, and in fact the package was removed some time ago from the weekly releases.

Comment: Ok, but how do I create a vector in first place? Do you have a sample? :)

Comment: @OscarRyz: `var v []t` or `v := []t{}` is all what's needed to have a ready to use vector `v` of `t`.